# Is in asp.net WebForms and in asp.net MVC5 some default DI container?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, webforms

I am trying find out, whether in asp.net WebForms and in asp.net MVC5 applications exists some default Dependency Injection container. It seems that there is no default DI container, but I want to know it certainly.

So my questions are:

1. Is in asp.net WebForms application default DI container?
2. Is in asp.net (not in asp.net core) MVC5 application default DI container?
3. If answer in 1. or in 2. is "yes" - what is name of the DI container and is good to use it?

Comment: No, those frameworks do **not** have a default, system-provided dependency injection component included. You can use any of the many third-party ones - but none are included in the base, out-of-the-box system

Comment: Actually, yes they have some injection dependencies. If you modify the site - say scripts and attempt to post in say JavaScript? You get this error message:

Comment: ==== invalid postback or callback argument. Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page. For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them. If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation

Answer (score 0):

yes, they do have some injection systems by defaut.

if you modify a control? Then you can and will get this error message:

***invalid postback or callback argument. Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page. For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them. If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation***

> what is name of the DI container and is good to use it?

I don't think you can mess or play or do anything much of value. So, really a non issue. As the above message shows - you in some cases have to disable Event Validation to get your page to work, or you can as the above error message suggests register the control + event on that page to get around this built in protection. So, I don't know the name of the DI container - but then again, we never care nor are we able to mess with it in a any significant ways that one would or could care about. So, you really only care that in those cases you can (might want) to disable this protection, or as the error message suggests you can (and have to) register the control + event to get around this built in protection - not much of a narrative beyond the above is required on your part.